# Mean value over a 3d matrix R

Tags: r

I have a 3d array like this

```
datamonth <- array(0, dim = c(length(LONG),length(LATG),length(YEAR)))

>dim(datamonth)
[1] 361 181  30
```

where the first two dimensions are Longitude and Latitude (I have a 1 deg spaced grid). What I would like to do is to calculate the mean value of datamonth for every grid point, e.g.

```
Cell 1 
LON -180 -179
LAT  -90 -89

year 1: MeanCell1_yr
year 2: MeanCell1_yr    .
.
.
year 30: MeanCell1_yr

MeanCell1TOT = mean(MeanCell1_yr)
```

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but check something like `apply(datamonth, c(1,2), mean)` pehaps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this:

```
rowMeans(datamonth, dims = 2)
```

It will be a lot faster than

```
apply(datamonth, c(1,2), mean)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add a detailed explanation about @flodel's solution:

The 'apply(datamonth, c(1,2), mean)' solution will calculate the mean along the 3rd dimension of 3D array.

```
avgData1 <- apply(datamonth, c(1,2), mean)
```

This solution is equalivant to the following with multiple lines of code:

```
dataList <- list()
for (i in 1:dim(datamonth)[3]){
    dataList[[l]] <- datamonth[,,i]
}
avgData2 <- Reduce('+', dataList)/length(dataList)

# check whether avgData1 and avgData2 are equal or not?
sum(avgData1-avgData2) # the difference should be 0
```